# Adding 2 files to zip archive with Java

Tags: java

I need to put 2 files in one zip archive using java. I use the following code and it works fine with one file. When I call the method with two files it doesn't throw any exception but I have broken file as a result

```
    private File createZipFile(File[] files) throws IOException {

        File zipFile = new File("D:\\zip.zip");

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream));

        for (File file: files) {
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream, 1024);

            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
            int count;
            while ((count = bufferedInputStream.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                zipOutputStream.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            bufferedInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();
        }

        zipOutputStream.close();

        return zipFile;
    }
```

Comment: I can not reproduce this. How do you know that your result file is invalid? I could properly unzip the result file (containing two files) with a command line `unzip`

Comment: It did work for two files, e.g I've put two pdf files and the code works. It did fail if the files are directories, since you haven't handled the recursiveness.

Comment: @VadOs please provide an [mcve]. It is especially important to know whether the files are, well, files, or directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are missing `zipOutputStream.closeEntry()` at the end of your loop.

Comment: `public void putNextEntry(ZipEntry e) throws IOException`- 
Begins writing a new ZIP file entry and positions the stream to the start of the entry data. **Closes the current entry if still active**